# How can i add a restart quiz button after the last quesetion. Also is there a way to reflect the specific div depending on the outcomes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is basically the idea.

1. 3 sets of questions with 2 choices each.
2. There will be 8 total outcomes.
3. Start with a "Start the quiz button".
4. I used radio buttons for the choices
5. Next question will be shown until the last question.
6. From the combination of answer. A Section will be displayed to replace the question sections to hide them. Depending on the combination, a content will be displayed.
7. There will be a "Restart quiz" button when the result content is shown to restart the quiz.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters intro-wrapper">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3 my-md-5">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <p>Some title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
            <div class="start-btn-wrapper">
                <a class="start-btn" href="#" id="startQuiz">Start the quiz <span>&#9658;</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-header">
                <h2 class="text-center" id="question"></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1" class="answer">
                        <label for="answer1" class="radio-text" id="choice1"></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2" class="answer">
                        <label for="answer2" class="radio-text" id="choice2"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="quiz-outcome" id="quizOutcome">
            <div class="set-1" data-outcome="Set 1">
                <h2>Some text title1</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-2" data-outcome="Set 2">
                <h2>Some text title2</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-3" data-outcome="Set 3">
                <h2>Some text title3</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-4" data-outcome="Set 4">
                <h2>Some text title4</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-5" data-outcome="Set 5">
                <h2>Some text title5</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-6" data-outcome="Set 6">
                <h2>Some text title6</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-7" data-outcome="Set 7">
                <h2>Some text title7</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-8" data-outcome="Set 8">
                <h2>Some text title8</h2>
                <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
const quizData = [
  {
    question: "This is question number 1",
    choices: ["Answer 1-1", "Answer 1-2"],
  },
  {
    question: "This is question number 2",
    choices: ["Answer 2-1", "Answer 2-2"],
  },
  {
    question: "This is question number 3",
    choices: ["Answer 3-1", "Answer 3-2"],
  },
];

function determineOutcome(answers) {
  const outcomes = {
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 1",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 2",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 3",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 4",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 5",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 6",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 7",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 8",
  };

  const combinationKey = answers.join(",");
  return outcomes[combinationKey] || "Could not determine your outcome.";
}

const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
const answerElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const radioTextElements = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
const startQuizButton = document.getElementById("startQuiz");
const quizBtnWrapper = document.querySelector(".start-btn-wrapper")

// Initialize quiz index and user answers
let quizIndex = -1;
const userAnswers = [];

// Function to update the quiz content
function updateQuiz() {
  quizIndex++;

  if (quizIndex < quizData.length) {
    const currentQuestion = quizData[quizIndex];
    questionElement.textContent = currentQuestion.question;

    currentQuestion.choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
      radioTextElements[index].textContent = choice;
    });

    // Clear radio selections
    answerElements.forEach((answer) => {
      answer.checked = false;
      console.log("is this working1");

    });
  } else {
    questionElement.textContent = "Quiz Complete!";
    radioTextElements.forEach((text) => {
      text.textContent = "";
      console.log("is this working2");
    });
    submitButton.disabled = true;
    console.log("is this working3");

    const outcome = determineOutcome(userAnswers);
    console.log(outcome);

    var outcomeElements = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz-outcome div');
    outcomeElements.forEach(function(outcomeElement) {
      var dataOutcome = outcomeElement.getAttribute('data-outcome');

      if (dataOutcome === outcome) {
        outcomeElement.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        outcomeElement.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}

startQuizButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  quizBtnWrapper.style.display = "none";
  updateQuiz();
});

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const selectedAnswer = Array.from(answerElements).find((answer) => answer.checked);
  if (selectedAnswer) {
    userAnswers.push(selectedAnswer.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    updateQuiz();
  }
});
</script>
```

Here's the complete [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62h4nbaq/)

I have pretty much all of it now. It's is not perfect like for example on the radio buttons. When it gets to the end it is still there. So my idea is to just cover it with a section that will show the result/content of that div with the result. This is where im not sure on how i will be able to display the specific div depending on the combination. I'm also thinking of having a restart button to restart the question whenever.

EDIT: i made an edit and used data-att* to match it with the outcome, seems to be working!!

Comment: Add a new element for your intro/complete message, so it's separate from the `.quiz-container` then [show](https://api.jquery.com/show/)/[hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) into-container/quiz-container as needed.

Comment: As your questions and outcomes are data-driven, it seems strange to then have the outcome in the HTML.  Move the set-n outcome/title into the outcomes variable and build the result from the data; as you do with with the questions.

Comment: @freedomn-m The reason i wanted the outcome in html is because there will be an image and some text content for each outcome results. I'm thinking it will be more easier to style them that way. Is there a way that i can match the outcome with the specific div?

Comment: Put the html id/class in the js variable, eg `const outcomes = { "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-1": "set-1",` then use that to locate which element to show, eg `$("." + outcomes[combinationKey]).fadeIn()` (as tagged [tag:jquery])

Comment: Suggestion: change your question/choices so that the answer has a key(id) / text, eg `choices: [ { key: "2-1", answer: "The first answer for question 2" }, { key: "2-2", answer:....` then when you convert to set, you don't need the full answer text in your outcome combination `outcomes = { "1-1,2-1,3-1" }` which will make it much easier to manage / adjust / change in the future.

Comment: @freedomn-m i made a little adjustment with the outcome, i think this is almost similar to your suggestion of using a key(id). Since the outcome will be constant anyway, since the result will still depend on the html coded on the div section is corresponds to. What do you think of this one? Sorry i'm still new to this so im not sure which one is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

to hide the buttons you could ad an id to the list  element:

```
<ul id="options">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1" class="answer">
        <label for="answer1" class="radio-text" id="choice1"></label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2" class="answer">
        <label for="answer2" class="radio-text" id="choice2"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your updateQuiz within the else add:
 `optionsElement.style.display = "none";` to remove the list from being displayed.

for a reset you can add a button and a few more element ids to have items displayed or not and then hav button change states and reset userchoices:

```
    <div class="row no-gutters intro-wrapper">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3 my-md-5">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <p>Some title</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
            <div class="start-btn-wrapper">
                <a class="start-btn" href="#" id="startQuiz">Start the quiz <span>&#9658;</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="quiz-header">
                <h2 class="text-center" id="question"></h2>
                <ul id="options">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1" class="answer">
                        <label for="answer1" class="radio-text" id="choice1"></label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2" class="answer">
                        <label for="answer2" class="radio-text" id="choice2"></label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <div>
              <p id = "outcome"></p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id="resetQuiz">Restart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quiz-outcome" id="quizOutcome">
            <div class="set-1">
                  <h2>Some text title1</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-2">
                <h2>Some text title2</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-3">
                <h2>Some text title3</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-4">
                <h2>Some text title4</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-5">
                <h2>Some text title5</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-6">
                <h2>Some text title6</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-7">
                <h2>Some text title7</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
            <div class="set-8">
                <h2>Some text title8</h2>
                  <p>Some description etc etc</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
const quizData = [
  {
    question: "This is question number 1",
    choices: ["Answer 1-1", "Answer 1-2"],
  },
  {
    question: "This is question number 2",
    choices: ["Answer 2-1", "Answer 2-2"],
  },
  {
    question: "This is question number 3",
    choices: ["Answer 3-1", "Answer 3-2"],
  },
];

function determineOutcome(answers) {
  const outcomes = {
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 1",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 2",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 3",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-1":
      "Set 4",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 5",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-1,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 6",
    "Answer 1-1,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 7",
    "Answer 1-2,Answer 2-2,Answer 3-2":
      "Set 8",
  };

  const combinationKey = answers.join(",");
  return outcomes[combinationKey] || "Could not determine your outcome.";
}

const questionElement = document.getElementById("question");
const optionsElement = document.getElementById("options");
const answerElements = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const radioTextElements = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-text");
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
const startQuizButton = document.getElementById("startQuiz");
const quizBtnWrapper = document.querySelector(".start-btn-wrapper")
const resetButton = document.getElementById("resetQuiz");
const outcomeElement = document.getElementById("outcome");


resetButton.style.display = "none";
outcomeElement.style.display = "none";

// Initialize quiz index and user answers
let quizIndex = -1;
const userAnswers = [];

// Function to update the quiz content
function updateQuiz() {
  quizIndex++;

  if (quizIndex < quizData.length) {
    const currentQuestion = quizData[quizIndex];
    questionElement.textContent = currentQuestion.question;

    currentQuestion.choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
      radioTextElements[index].textContent = choice;
    });

    // Clear radio selections
    answerElements.forEach((answer) => {
      answer.checked = false;
      console.log("is this working1");

    });
  } else {
    optionsElement.style.display = "none";
      outcomeElement.style.display = "initial";
    questionElement.textContent = "Quiz Complete!";
    radioTextElements.forEach((text) => {
      text.textContent = "";
      console.log("is this working2");
    });
    submitButton.style.display = "none";
    console.log("is this working3");
  
    // Determine the outcome and display it 
    const outcome = determineOutcome(userAnswers);
    //const outcomeElement = document.createElement("p");
    outcomeElement.textContent = "Your outcome: " + outcome;
    //document.getElementById("quiz").appendChild(outcomeElement);
    resetButton.style.display = "initial";
  }
}

startQuizButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  quizBtnWrapper.style.display = "none";
  updateQuiz();
});

submitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const selectedAnswer = Array.from(answerElements).find((answer) => answer.checked);
  if (selectedAnswer) {
    userAnswers.push(selectedAnswer.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    updateQuiz();
  }
});

resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  resetButton.style.display = "none";
  userAnswers.length = 0;
  quizIndex = -1;
  updateQuiz();
  quizOutcome.style.display = "none";
  optionsElement.style.display = "flex";
  submitButton.style.display = "initial";
  outcomeElement.style.display = "none";
});
```